# last element of the hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am sending several parameters for the printing of tickets in pdf

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "list"=>{"client_0801541"=>"0801541", "client_0801554"=>"0801554", "client_0801554"=>"0801554"}, "subaction"=>"print selected clients"}
```

I need to print each client on a different page, for this I use a start_new_page at the end of showing the client's code, but in that way after the last client leaves a blank page. How could I make it so that for each client it verifies if it is the last one of the array? I have tried the following:

```
  def client
    @client.each do |(c,client_id)|
      draw_text "#{client_id}", :at => [0,22], :size => 5, :style => :bold
      start_new_page unless client_id == @client.map{|e|[e.c, e.client_id]}.client_id.last
    end
  end
```

Comment: Try to avoid quoting variables for no reason. Here `"#{client_id}"` can be `client_id`. If you need to coerce that into a string for whatever reason `client_id.to_s` makes it clear what you're doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

```
@clients.each do |(c, client_id)|
  draw_text "#{client_id}", :at => [0,22], :size => 5, :style => :bold
  start_new_page unless client_id == @clients.values.last
end
```

You could also try:

```
@clients.each_with_index do |(c, client_id), i|
  draw_text "#{client_id}", :at => [0,22], :size => 5, :style => :bold
  start_new_page unless i == @clients.length - 1
end
```

As Tadman suggests, you could also speed this up by doing:

```
def client
  @clients_length = @clients.length - 1
  @clients.each_with_index do |(c, client_id), i|
    draw_text "#{client_id}", :at => [0,22], :size => 5, :style => :bold
    start_new_page unless i == @clients_length
  end
end
```

Your original code:

```
def client
  @client.each do |(c,client_id)|
    draw_text "#{client_id}", :at => [0,22], :size => 5, :style => :bold
    start_new_page unless client_id == @client.map{|e|[e.c, e.client_id]}.client_id.last
  end
end
```

Seems banged up, minimally, because:

- You're using `map` on every iteration, which seems wasteful.
- In `@client.map{|e|[e.c, e.client_id]}`, `.c` and `.client_id` aren't methods on `Array`.
- `.client_id` isn't a method on `Array`.
- Probably other stuff.

BTW, last two `keys` and `values` in your `list` are identical. I don't know if that's an error. But, if that's what you intend, then you may have other problems.

Also BTW, the title of your question says 'last element of the array', but you're working with a `hash`, not an `array`.

Comment: The `each_with_index` approach is faster especially if you capture `@clients.length` into a variable in advance.

Comment: @jvillian, thanks a lot my friend, this worked with no problems